# QGIS error while importing .shp file, missing geometry (gdal issue)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gdal, error

In Manjaro Linux (Antergos as well and so I suppose vanilla Arch), with QGIS 3.2 + gdal from [official repository](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/qgis/), and QGIS 3.4 + gdal-ecw from [archgeotux repository](https://archgeotux.sourceforge.io/), when I try to add a .shp the output is

```
ERROR 1: Error in fread() reading object of size XX at offset YYY from .shp file
```

And the result is that some of the geometry in the .shp are missing.

(note that this error doesn't appear with all my .shp, some of them work perfectly)

See this for reference: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4203, the problem is the same but no solution.

Meanwhile, with Ubuntu 18.04 for example (but Windows as well) all my .shp files load correctly.

Anyone with Manjaro or Arch have a clue about this?

Comment: What if you rewrite some of your problematic shapefiles with your Ubuntu version of GDAL, does the new copy open without error?

Comment: @user30184 how can I rewrite them? Open with Ubuntu qgis and then export to another .shp?

Comment: Working with corrupt data files is the quintessential definition of *undefined behavior*. Even if this were reproducible, it would hardly be a software issue.

Comment: The safest way is to use Ubuntu or Windows to export to another format, like geopackage. Maybe the .shx file is broken.

Comment: Import in Ubuntu and export in a new.shp and reimport in Manjaro fix the issue. But the question is: why it works with Ubuntu and not with Manjaro? Is a gdal issue i suppose.

Comment: Manjaro must contain older GDAL sources which are not patched to read certain invalid shapefiles.