# Cannot see some shapefiles in QGIS Madeira 3.4.1

Tags: qgis

We have been working in QGIS without any problem. However in this new QGIS Madeira we are having some issues with some shapefiles. We open them we can see the atribute table but we cannot see the geometries (small file 6 geometries). However the same file can be correctly opened in QGIS 2.18.20 or in ArcGIS.
If the file is saved in QGIS 2.18.20 into a shapefile I can open it in QGIS Madeira.

Comment: could it be a projection problem? are you loading the shapefiles into an empty project or into an existing one? have you tried right click and zoom to layer?

Comment: I wonder if it could be somehow the same issue than in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303114/qgis-error-while-importing-shp-file-missing-geometry-gdal-issue.

Comment: No problem with projection all the same. Empty project. Yes. It seems similar issue some shapes work others do not no apparent reason. If i open same shape in QGIS 2.18.20 and save it it will open correctly. All shapes work well in ArcGis/ArcView. All shapes work well in previous QGIS version

Comment: You need to figure out what's different between the shapefiles that work and the ones that don't. Did they come from different sources?

Comment: Same source this is the issue https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2018-October/049218.html